# Как подключить локальную функцию из другой директории в Go?

Tags: golang, echo

Создал проект (вне пути `GOPATH` или `GOROOT`) на фреймворке `Echo`. Получилась следующая структура:

```
lolo
--views
----count_private.go
--statics
--go.mod
--go.sum
--logs.log
--main.go
```

Код в `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "views"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    // group_module := e.Group("/module")

    // group_module.GET("/f_count_private", views.f_count_private(e))

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

Код в `count_private.go`

```
package views

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

func f_count_private(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
}
```

При запуске кода через команду
`$ go run main.go`
выдается ошибка:
`main.go:4:2: package views is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\views)`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обойти ошибку и сделать так, чтобы я мог в `main()` использовать функцию `f_count_private(...)` из другого файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пакет `views` нужно импортировать по полному пути. Например, если в go.mod у вас написано `module example.org`, то импортировать нужно  `example.org/views`.

Но даже так функция `f_count_private` не будет видна. Имя этой функции начинается с маленькой буквы, что в go означает внутреннюю функцию пакета. Имена экспортируемых функций должны начинаться с заглавной буквы: `F_count_private`

Но если вы хотите сделать эту функцию приватной, то есть в вашем модуле ей можно пользоваться, а другие модули не смогли её вызывать, то вам нужно сделать пакет `internal/views`. Публичные функции из этого пакета будут видны внутри вашего модуля, но недоступны другим модулям.

Я сделал [небольшой проект для иллюстрации](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/tree/main/go/1440921)

В этом проекте два модуля, `mod1` и `mod2`. В модуле `mod1` есть пакет `internal/views`, в котором определена функция `CountPrivate`. Эта функция вызывается в `mod1/main.go` без проблем.

При компиляции идентичного файла `mod2/main.go` компилятор ругается:

```
mod2$ go run main.go
package command-line-arguments
        main.go:4:5: use of internal package example.org/mod1/internal/views not allowed
```